# Usage of "would have" in real-past situations

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

> It's unfortunate that Stephanie's face wasn't captured at this moment
> because she would have no doubt been immediately struck by the
> psychological reaction known as fight or flight. Her brain ***would
> have just triggered the influx*** of a specific cocktail of hormones
> in order to prepare her to either stay and deal with a threat or try
> and run away to the safety. Stephanie chooses to fight. (It is from a
> video on interrogation of a murderer)

This usage of "would have" always confuses me because most sources only explain one usage of "would have" , which is forming a type 3 conditional sentence (For example: If it had rained, you would have gotten wet. ) . I know this is not a hypothetical conditional. It is something that really happened at that time in the past. I wonder why the narrator didn't usage past perfect instead of "would have + v3" ? " ...***her brain had just triggered the***..."

Comment: I do read it as a hypothetical: *If her face **had been** captured, her brain **would have** triggered XYZ hormones.* This doesn't really make sense until you realize that we can't say for sure whether this happened, because we don't actually have footage of her face at this time to confirm it. (I'm grasping a little to make the paragraph grammatically sound.)

Comment: Disagree. Stephanie likely **was** immediately struck by fight-or-flight, and her brain likely **did** trigger an influx of hormones. This isn't the unreal result of having her picture taken. It's the consequence of something that did happen earlier in the context.

Answer (score 1):

All modals have an [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) meaning (about the speaker's knowledge or certainty) separate from their [deontic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) one (about objective possibilities and obligations).

This one is epistemic: *Her brain would have just triggered...* means something like ***I conclude that** her brain just triggered...*

Comment: Thanks, is there any chance that you could provide me with a resource explaining this specific usage because I can't find it or could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: The speaker cannot assert that her brain triggered the influx (signalled directly by _no doubt_) but assumes or decduces that that is what happened. Epistemic _must_ is more common, but "her brain must have triggered the influx ... " has the connotation of "I've just worked out or realised that ...". All modals can be used epistemically, and the _would_ here has the nature of a natural and plausible conclusion.